# css INLINE-BLOCK div align center but keep insider elements still align left

Tags: css, alignment

I need help with this simple example which I designed just to understand INLINE-BLOCK related layouts. It's simple:left and right parts, and inside right part there're up and down elements. I want the right part in the center of the [screen width minus left part], while inside right part h3 and p elements align left. I added a border just to understand if I've fully used space of the righthand screen. Sometimes my hands are tied so I can not change html, so I need pure css method.
I do have read some of the similar questions here, but after some tests I'm still lost ---- for example, giving a width:500px to right part? but I need right part CENTERED for different screens! Another problem: right part text-align:center will also influence inside elements; inside elements text-align:left will also influence right part.
Please note: this is about inline-block....and pure css.
Appreciate any response.

```css
.left{
display:inline-block;
background:aqua;
}
.right{
border:solid;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<OCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        
<div class="whole">
  <div class="left"><p>lefter</p></div>

  <div class="right">
    <h3>upperright</h3>
    <div class="lowerright"><p>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The attached image shows my thought.[image]

Comment: please add a screenshot of how you want it. thanks

Comment: You can use `flexbox`

Comment: @XenioGracias Thanks, I just added an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added

```
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translatex(-50%);
```

to .right. hope this helps. thanks

```css
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  background: aqua;
}

.right {
  border: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

```html
<OCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="whole">
      <div class="left">
        <p>lefter</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <h3>upperright</h3>
        <div class="lowerright">
          <p>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdd</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This one is neat and near perfect!